# How to enable type checking of mjs files in VS Code

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code

I have a project with js files, where I enabled type checking across multiple modules (highlighting wrong parameters etc of function imported from different module) in VS Code by creating this jsconfig.json:

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "checkJs": true
  }
}
```

Now, I read that typescript 4.5 supports mjs files https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27957

So I installed typescript 4.5 beta, node 17, and modified jsconfig.json to this:

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "node12",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "checkJs": true
  }
}
```

but it still doesn't work for mjs files, and I also get this error in jsconfig.json:

> Argument for '--module' option must be: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd',
> 'system', 'umd', 'es6', 'es2015', 'es2020', 'esnext'

Any idea how to enable type checking for mjs files across multiple modules?

Comment: Any luck on this? Maybe you need to use node v16 (latest LTS), not node v17?

Comment: Official docs page: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/esm-node.html

Answer (score 3):

Consider using these tsconfig.json options:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "NodeNext",
    "target": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "NodeNext"
  },
  "include": ["**/*.mjs"]
}
```

=======

Here's ALL the changes I did along with adding .mjs support. I don't think they are all strictly necessary, but I want to share for completeness:

Modified my package.json `type-check` script:

```
"type-check": "tsc --pretty --noEmit && tsc --pretty --noEmit --project tsconfig.mjs.json",
```

Here's my tsconfig.mjs.json file:

```json
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "NodeNext",
    "target": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "NodeNext"
  },
  "include": ["**/*.mjs"]
}
```

Run:

```sh
yarn add @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin @typescript-eslint/parser --dev
yarn remove typescript
yarn add typescript # use latest
```

Likely, you will get an error that you need to use typescript nightly build to actually type-check mjs files. Run:

```sh
yarn remove typescript
yarn add typescript@next --dev
```

Answer (score 1):

I know that you were asking for a solution to typecheck *all* `.mjs` files automatically, but maybe the following might be interesting for others:

As long as you only have a few `.mjs` files that you want to typecheck with TypeScript, you can just add `//@ts-check` in the first line of each `.mjs` file.

Check the Typescript [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/intro-to-js-ts.html#ts-check) for more details.