# How can I specify TypeScript Module and Target in `.js` files?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a `.mjs` file:

```js
console.log(await foo())
```

I want this code to be type-checked (there's more in this file of course ;) ) so I add `// @ts-check`

```js
// @ts-check
console.log(await foo())
```

but now tsserver shows me this error:

> Top-level 'await' expressions are only allowed when the 'module' option is set to 'es2022', 'esnext', 'system', or 'nodenext', and the 'target' option is set to 'es2017' or higher.

How can I fix this?

### Solutions I have thought of:

1. adding a `jsconfig.json` to my project

- I don't want any extra files in my project

2. Don't use top-level `await`

- In this case I could just do `foo().then(console.log)`

### Ideal solution

A comment I can place next to `@ts-check` like

```js
// @ts-check
// @ts-module es2022
// @ts-target es2022

console.log(await foo())
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69645080/how-to-enable-type-checking-of-mjs-files-in-vs-code

Comment: This is my first solution: adding a config file.  I want to keep this all in one file