# 'Property doesn't exist' error with imported module in Svelte

Tags: javascript, decimal, svelte, svelte-3, big.js

I want to use big.js or decimal.js to perform accurate calculations of decimal numbers in my basic Svelte app. To test it, I have imported the module in my App.svelte file:

```
import Decimal from "../node_modules/decimal.js/decimal.mjs";
import Big from "../node_modules/big.js/big.mjs";
```

However, when I create a Big object and use its built-in functions, I get an error in my IDE (Visual Studio Code), but the code works as expected in the console:

```
let myNumber = 3.2;
let secondNumber = new Big(myNumber).div(2);

Error: Property 'div' does not exist on type 'Big'
```

How can I get my IDE to recognise imported objects from modules? To clarify, I am not using typescript.

Comment: What do you see if you log out `new Big(newNumber)`. `console.log('big', new Big(newNumber))`

Comment: I just realised 'newNumber' should be 'myNumber' (I've amended my question). However, this is what I see in the console if I put `console.log("big", new Big(myNumber));`
`big Big {s: 1, e: 0, c: Array(2), constructor: ƒ}`

Comment: could it be related to this? `import Big from "../node_modules/big.js/big.mjs";`

as far as I know you should just import modules like: `import Big from "big.js";` or like `import Big from "big.js/big.mjs";`
Could you try it out?

Comment: Just tried it out. If I do that, my IDE cannot locate the module files and they stop working altogether. It's odd, big.js and decimal.js still works in my project as-is, but the IDE keeps throwing the mentioned error because it doesn't seem to recognise them.

I appreciate you coming up with possible solutions though! It a hard one.

Comment: @Slidder So just to be sure, the error only shows up in your IDE, but works when you run the actual app in the browser?

Comment: Yes, exactly that. And I want to fix it because the error messages clutter the project and are obscuring genuine errors.

Comment: What IDE or code editor are you using? Mac/linux/pc? If you share a minimal version of the app that creates the error you are talking about, I am willing to take a look at it. I know how annoying those red squiggly lines can be

Comment: Sure! Windows PC, using Visual Studio Code ver 1.70.2. Is that enough information?

Comment: Could you share a repo to the app with this issue? Or maybe a link to an app with the minimal code to reproduce this?

Comment: Here you go, but it would need to be copied into the IDE and the decimal.js module installed locally. Unfortunately, I don't know how (or if) a module can be imported using a URL only: https://svelte.dev/repl/11a837890af44b11860922662d0195bc?version=3.59.1

Thanks again.

Comment: Did you install the Svelte plugin for VSCode?

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69645080/how-to-enable-type-checking-of-mjs-files-in-vs-code